# C# Handling user input in multi threaded selenium windows form

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, webdriver

In the function 'processAccounts' I would like to take user input to dynamically create a url string. I have absolutely zero idea where to begin. I did try some dialog boxes but it would be much cleaner to use some kind of queue that does not freeze the threads that aren't waiting for user input.

```
    private void processAccounts(object currentAccount)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
        var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        ChromeDriver x = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
        x.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        string input = ""; // how do I take input dynamically here?
        x.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/search?as_q=" + input);
    }



    private void goClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] accountList = { "acc1:pass1", "acc2:pass2", "acc2:pass2", "acc3:pass3", "acc4:pass4", "acc5:pass5", "acc6:pass6", "acc7:pass7", "acc8:pass8", "acc9:pass9" };

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;

        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            Parallel.ForEach(accountList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, currentAccount =>
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                processAccounts(currentAccount);

                BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    WriteProgress(currentAccount);
                }));
            });
        }, tokenSource.Token);

        task.ContinueWith((t) =>
                BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    SignalCompletion();
                }))
        );
    }


    void WriteProgress(string fileName)
    {
        progressBar.Visible = true;
        progressBar.Value += 1;
    }

    private void SignalCompletion()
    {
                lblFinished.Text = "done";
    }
```

Comment: You expect a user to be sitting there providing input or ??? Can you not read the selections from a file before the test starts?

Comment: user enters input yes